# changes in bash_profile not getting reflected linux

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell

Below is the `.bash_profile` file that I have edited. The changes I make here are not getting reflected when I use `echo $JAVA_HOME` or `echo $PATH`.

When I use `$PATH`, I get `/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin` which is not found in any of the `.bash_profile`s or `.bash_rc`s.

How can I make my `.bash_profile` work?

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

export PATH=/sbin/:$PATH

export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export JAVA_HOME=/export/home/lg199447/dev/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/java

export PATH=$PATH:/export/home/lg199447/dev/jdk1.7.0_51/bin
```

Note: 
I am trying to login to a server from an OS X terminal using `ssh` and once I'm logged in my terminal was showing **`$`** followed by my cursor. I was unable to use my arrow keys and tab. So I manually stared bash by executing bash in `/bin` directory. This changed my terminal as `lg199447@VDCALD564 /]$` and I was able to use terminal in a normal way I use in mac.

Comment: Shouldn't the JAVA_HOME variable be `/export/home/lg199447/dev/jdk1.7.0_51`, not the path of the java executable?

Comment: You are correct. But I am yet to get root access. I was trying it out till then. But that shouldn't be a problem with java right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sounds like you login shell on the linux machine is not `bash`, but some other shell variant. `~/.bash_profile` is only sourced for bash login shells, so if you just execute `bash`, it's not.

Either make `/bin/bash` your login shell (using the command `chsh -s /bin/bash`), or start bash using `bash -l`, then it should work.

Another option would be to place your startup code in `~/.bashrc`, which is sourced for for all interactive bash sessions (except if explicitly disabled with the `--norc` option).

Comment: $ echo $0 gave me -ksh. Looks like my base shell is ksh.

Comment: By changing shell wont cause any problem to server? Because I am configuring server for the first time and not sure if it is safe to changing to bash. Is there any way to set path for the ksh shell that I am using?

Comment: No, it shouldn't make much different, it only changes which shell is started for interactive login sessions for your user, it doesn't affect anything else on the server. --- and on a personal note - `ksh` - ughhh - change it as quickly as possible :)

Comment: Note taken. Will do it right away as I get my admin access :D

Comment: `chsh`, if available, should work as unprivileged user without admin rights. It lets you change your login shell to any of the shells listeed in `/etc/shells`. Another note: most shells read `~/.profile`(including ksh and bash if no .bash_profile is found) when started as login shells, so that would be another option where you could put your exports...

Comment: When I use `$ chsh -s /bin/bash`, it says `chsh: can only change local entries; use ypchsh instead.` And I tried adding ~/.profile and added paths. But it don't work. But opening bash with -l seems to work.

Comment: It seems you are not using /etc/passwd. Your server is using nis (yp). /use ypchsh instead.